# cannot drop the table dbo.Images because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, entity-framework-migrations

I deleted a table on Server Explorer and it model, now when i try to update the database it says

> Cannot drop the table dbo.Images because it does not exist or you not
>   have permission

I cannot updated database now and add other tables, i dont want the table anymore. Please help!

Comment: deleting the table from a server explorer is equivalent to dropping the table with the query. 
so unless you have a backup, you have lost the table.period

Comment: The migration you are trying to run using update-database can not remove the table because it doesn't exist. Change that migration.

Answer (score 8):

Some pending migration you are trying to run using `update-database` can not remove the table because it doesn't exist.

You should be able to figure out which migration is causing the issue by looking at the stack trace and remove the code from within it's `Up()` method which is trying to remove your `dbo.Images` table.

Comment: remove the code from within it's Up() method -- I should have thought that :D. Thanks friend.

Answer (score 1):

Create **Images** table in the database and run the **update-database** again from Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually delete the migration(s) you did previously that contain the table dbo.Images. Once you do that you shouldn't be getting issues to migrate again then update the database :). I know my answer is very late just to help others with the same issue :)

Answer (score -3):

Delete all files except Configuration.cs under Migration folder

[image]